# Как cкопировать значения атрибутов src <img> и вставить их атрибутом href в тег <a> (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

есть такое дерево:

```
<div class="grid">

<a href="">
<img src="qwerty1" width="450" height="301" /> 
</a>

<a href=""> 
<img src="qwerty2" alt="" />
</a> 

<a href=""> 
<img src="qwerty3" alt="" /> 
</a>

</div>
```

как можно в ссылки загнать значения тегов src, что бы атрибут href каждой ссылки соответсвовал тегу src вложеного изображения, помогите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно выбрать все элементы a у которых есть дочерний элемент img и для всех выбранных элементов установить атрибут

```
$("a:has(img)").each(function() {
  this.href = $('img', this).attr('src'):
});
```

Comment: @Igor Исправил. Нужно each()

Answer (score 0):

Давно не импользовал jQuery, поэтому в нюансах могу и наврать, но общий принцип примерно такой:

```
$(".grid a").each(
  function(i1, o1) {
    $(this).find('img').each(
      function(i2, o2) {
        $(this).parent.attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Код далек от идеала, если внутри  будет несколько картинок, то вставится урл последней, чтобы этого не было, нужно добавить дополнительные проверки.